# If I insert or drag the Order ID field onto the group header, which Order ID will I see for each group?

Tags: crystal-reports

use in crystal report insert or drag the order id----

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to assume you mean grouping on records that have more than one Order ID (or any other field).

If you place a field in a group header that takes on multiple values throughout the group, the FIRST record's value in that group will display in the header. Though, this isn't generally a good practice for a few reasons. One is that a single record's value usually won't have much meaning across the group. Another is that any time you re-sort the report the group header's value will potentially change. If you're looking for a particular value, I would consider using something like a Summary instead so you have more control over what is displayed without worrying about preserving the order.